# div-header with no free space on top + sides

Tags: html, css

I need a div-header like the blue facebook header which has no free space on top and on the left/right side.

My actually code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>

        <style type="text/css">

            div#header {
                height: 100px;
                background-color: #3B5998;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
                padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>  
        <div id="header">
        </div>          
    </body>

</html>
```

I add extra no marigin and no padding, but i still have some free space on all 4 sides of my header...

Comment: add a style for the body to remove the padding and margins in the body element.

Comment: Also, consider using a full CSS reset: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}`

`#header {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #3B5998;
}`

Answer (score 0):

By default every browsers puts some amount of margin/padding around the body of the document.

To remove it you can add a css style in your html

```css
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Also, it is worth noticing that browsers attach insert various kinds of styles to elements, and these styles can be very different in different browsers. There are some style sheet files out there that can fix it, one of them could be found here

http://www.cssreset.com/